# Custom error in validation is not show in h:message

Tags: jsf-1.2

I want to show a custom message when user insert a wrong input for a Double value but when i test my application i always see the default error message.

That's my custom messages.properties:

```
`javax.faces.convert.DoubleConverter.CONVERSION=My Conversion Error(Double)
javax.faces.convert.DoubleConverter.CONVERSION_detail=My Conversion Error(Double)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION=My Conversion Error
javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION_detail=My Conversion Error(Double)
javax.faces.validator.NOT_IN_RANGE=My Validation Error
javax.faces.validator.NOT_IN_RANGE_detail=My Validation Error
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.LIMIT=Validation Limit Double
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.LIMIT_detail=Validation Limit Double
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.TYPE=Error Type Double
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.TYPE_detail = Error Type Double
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Requested!!
`
```

And here my faces.config

```
`<application>
<message-bundle>it.exaple.messages.MyMsg</message-bundle>
</application>`
```

And here my page:

```
`<td>
<h:inputText id="Value" value="#{user.value}" required="true">
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.0" maximum="200.0"/></h:inputText>
<h:message for="username" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" style="color:red"/>
</td>`
```

It's really strange because when i test my application with an empty value i can read my customized message, but when i try to insert a string i see the default error message!! Same thing happen when i put a to high or too low value!

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: `<message-bundle>it.exaple.messages.MyMsg</message-bundle>` did you mean "example"?

Comment: yes..i mispelled the name of the class but i am sure that is used by my application because when i test with an empty value i can read my custom error message!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must override these default message to validate range of double. And I hope you have defined `user.value` as double in your managed bean.

```
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MAXIMUM
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MINIMUM
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE
```